# PHP Call non static function with static way

Tags: php

What happens when we calling non-static functions with static way?
Like this :

```
class test
{
    public function hello()
    {
        return "say hello";
    }
}

class foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo test::hello();
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
```

Comment: what is that parenthesis on the class name declaration? most likely an error, try it

Comment: `Strict standards: Non-static method test::hello() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`, you're welcome! You can download PHP from here so you can try yourself rather than having to ask the outcome of every piece of code, as that's probably quite a slow way to develop! http://php.net/downloads.php

Comment: i fixed issue, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get `Strict standards: Non-static method test::hello() should not be called statically`

and your Class declaration is not good, right way is this

```
class test
{
    public function hello()
    {
        return "say hello";
    }
}

class foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo test::hello();
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
```

Laravel uses `Facade` to give illusion that you are using `static` method, you can also use `Facade` to call method like `test::hello();`

[Here is a good read on `Facade`](http://www.giorgiosironi.com/2010/01/practical-php-patterns-facade.html)

Answer (score 0):

Fast answer: You get a strict warning.

More details: If the variable $this is used in the function called it refers to the object where the function got called, not the class containing the function itself.

> Strict standards: Non-static method hello should not be called
>   statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Comment: What happens  when we receive strict warning?
It will be cause performance issue or other issue?

Comment: I do not know about performance issues I haven't tested, but I don't think so. I am actually using this flawed design to be able to stay DRY on a bad code usage... Works perfect for me once notices are turned off. I do know that we have over commented the function to be sure...